# Unable to get Release SourceBranch name from the environmental variables in azure devops

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a requirement for triggering an agent in a stage when the build is coming from pipeline CI "A 1".

When I put a condition `eq(variables['Release.Artifacts.{A 1}.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/main')` in the Agent pool and deployed it, I got the following error.

[image: Error_screenshot]

What is the exact conditional expression that should be used so that I will be getting the source branch name?

Note that, I don't want to change my CI name.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please edit the question to include any necessary source code, data, and error messages as text. Consider [these reasons and guidelines](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557).

Answer (score 0):

Based on my test, the condition (`eq(variables['Release.Artifacts.{Alias}.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/main')`)  can work as expected.

You need to check if the variable name is correct.

The `{A 1}` in your Release Pipeline variable is the Release Artifacts Alias instead of the Build Pipeline name.

You can check the Alias name in `Release Artifacts  -> Source alias`

[image]

You can directly use the Alias in your variable or you can modify it to use the new  name.

For example: `Release.Artifacts.test.SourceBranch`

On the other hand, since you are using build artifacts, you can also use the variable : `BUILD.SOURCEBRANCH`

For example:

`eq(variables['BUILD.SOURCEBRANCH'], 'refs/heads/main')`